# IOS - How to remove NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint from a view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I am having issues getting rid of a pesky `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint` that is breaking the auto-layout width constraints of some UITextView.

I have a UITableviewCell that contains a text view, and the text view's height is dynamically set based on the content of the text view's text using

```
    self.table.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension;
    self.table.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 200;
```

This works pretty well when auto-layout is used (I am setting my constraints via the interface and not code). However, I noticed that the widths of the text views are conflicting with `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint` - and the end result is the width constraint on my text view is being removed.

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000012ff070 h=--& v=--& UITextView:0x7fde2f09e600'At teenfvfed'.width == 89.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001292210 UITextView:0x7fde2f09e600'At teenfvfed'.width == 293   (active)>"
)
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001292210 UITextView:0x7fde2f09e600'At teenfvfed'.width == 293   (active)>
```

The common answer I see online is to add `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on the text view, but this doesn't have any effect and `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint` remains. Any help would be greatly appreciated to remove this!

Comment: It's a text view, not a label.

Comment: The text view is created in the storyboard? But then the default is not to have translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints set to true, so it sounds like maybe you've set it yourself in the storyboard. Unfortunately we can't see the storyboard from here.

Comment: correct - the text view is created in the storyboard in this case (and I've tried to manually set it to false anyway to eliminate the possibility)

Comment: Yes but that's too late. If the text view comes out of the storyboard with this conflict present, you can't fix the problem in code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.text.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.setNeedsLayout()
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```